# How do I create a Python virtual environment in the Ubuntu on Windows App using 'venv' rather than 'virtualenv'?

Tags: python3, virtualenv

I am using the Ubuntu on Windows App running on Windows Subsystem for Linux. So an initial question is if Python virtual environments is supported. Given my as yet limited understanding of Python virtual environments I would think that they are supported in the Ubuntu on Windows App. Here is the version info:

> Windows Ubuntu App 1804.2019.521.0
>
> Ubuntu release 18.04 (bionic)
>
> Python Version 3.6.7 (as best I remember this was installed by default).

My motivation for wanting to use `venv` is this reddit post:

> venv by nature of being part of Python itself has access to the internals of Python which means it can do things the right way with far fewer hacks...  ...So venv can be thought of virtualenv done right, with the blessing and support of the Python developers.

Similar questions came up when I entered my question, but I didn't find one that solved my problem.

One post:

> Since you specifically installed `python3.6` instead of Ubuntu's default `python3` version, which is `python3.5`, you have to install `python3.6-venv` instead of `python3-venv` since that would resolve to `python3.5-venv`. To do so, you can use `sudo apt install python3.6-venv`

Another post from 01/2018 said that `python3.6 -m venv myvenv` worked after reinstalling Python3.6.4. I'm avoiding re-installation for the time being.

Here is what I tried to create a virtual environment:

1) Opened Ubuntu

2) Went to the directory where I want to create the virtual environment.

```
 /home/dgrucza/python-virtual-environments
```

3) Entered `python3 -m venv env` This returned the following:

> The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
>   available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
>   package using the following command.
>
> apt-get install python3-venv
>
> You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
>   package, recreate your virtual environment.
>
> Failing command: ['/home/dgrucza/python-virtual-environments/evn/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']

4)Tried to install venv by entering `sudo apt-get install python-venv` After entering my password at the prompt this returned the following:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Package python3-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'python3-venv' has no installation candidate

5) Also tried entering `python3.6 -m venv myenv`, but received the same message.

> The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
>   available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
>   package using the following command.
>
> apt-get install python3-venv
>
> You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
>   package, recreate your virtual environment.
>
> Failing command: ['/home/dgrucza/myenv/bin/python3.6', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']

Comment: For the system's default instance of Python 3, you should just need to install `python3-venv`. I don't expect any problems or conflicts/confusions if you don't have any custom Python versions installed. So do you have that already and it doesn't work? If so, please provide what exactly happens instead, like complete output and error messages.

Comment: I've added the info you asked for. As best I remember my installation of Ubuntu is as it was when I installed it except for a few folders that I added in my home directory.

Comment: Do you have the Universe repositories enabled?  If not, that'll be one of the problems.

Comment: I executed `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and got this response:

`'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.`

Answer (score 0):

What I did so far:

1. Open Terminal
2. Go to desired directory
3. Type `python3 -m venv name_of_virtual_env`

If it doesn't work, could you please update your question to show the output of the Terminal?
**EDIT**
I just tested venv install on a virtual machine Lubuntu 19.04:
`sudo apt install python3-venv`
I could then create a virtual environment with above-mentionned command. However I already had **Spyder3** installed so some dependencies could have come with it.
And as suggested by Thomas Ward, I share my sources:
[image: Software sources]

Comment: Thanks. I should know better by now. I've added this info to my question.

Comment: The weird point if that "sudo apt-get install python-venv" doesn't work. Would you please try it again after typing "sudo apt update"? ANd if it still doesn't work, would you give a change to installing Spyder3 (a Python IDE) first and try again with python-venv?

Comment: I ran `sudo apt update' followed by 'sudo apt upgrade`, and the `sudo apt install python3-venv` ran successfully as did `sudo python3 -m venv env`.

Comment: Should I summarize this in another answer so it is more readable?

Comment: I should have know to update everything, but I'm still new to Ubuntu and Linux. It would be good to know conceptually what was preventing installation of venv.